# Creating Indexes Within View and Speeding up Spatial Queries Over View?

Tags: qgis, postgis, performance

I´m trying to add a view from postgis using QGIS, what´s facile. The problem is that it´s taking too long to load it and to perform any kind of operation, for example, as simple as counting rows. It´s a complex view, with 627 rows, and large geometric attribute.

Is it possible to create indexes within a view?

It must be told that geometric features repeat over the View, I mean, the same feature appears twice or even more along the View.

Is that what is limiting my performance?

---

The Postgres/PostGIS is actually running on a remote CentOS server which is in the same network as my desktop (no firewalls or proxy). The view query requires 68531 ms to run, but when I load it to QGIS, if I may say, it stucks.

```
SELECT h.gleba, sum(h.potencial) AS potencial, sum(h.parc_sem_req) AS parc_sem_req, sum(h.parc_com_req) AS parc_com_req, h.fronteira, h.regional, h.gleba_situacao, h.the_geom, 
        CASE
            WHEN h.categoria = '>1mf'::text THEN sum(h.potencial)
            ELSE 0::numeric
        END AS maior_que_um, 
        CASE
            WHEN h.categoria = '<1mf'::text THEN sum(h.potencial)
            ELSE 0::numeric
        END AS menor_que_um, h.assent_prev_nro, h.consulta_resultado, sum(h.total_parc) AS total_parc, h.gid_gleba
   FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.id) t.gleba, t.total_parc, t.potencial, t.id, t.fronteira, t.regional, 
                CASE
                    WHEN t.tamanho_mf >= 1.00000::double precision THEN '>1mf'::text
                    WHEN t.tamanho_mf < 1.00000::double precision THEN '<1mf'::text
                    ELSE t.tamanho_mf::text
                END AS categoria, 
                CASE
                    WHEN t.situacao_processo IS NULL THEN count(1)
                    ELSE 0::bigint
                END AS parc_sem_req, 
                CASE
                    WHEN t.situacao_processo IS NOT NULL THEN count(1)
                    ELSE 0::bigint
                END AS parc_com_req, t.assent_prev_nro, t.consulta_resultado, t.gleba_situacao, t.the_geom, t.gid_gleba
           FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id) count(1) AS total_parc, p.id, p.gleba, round(p.area_ha_utm / d.mod_fisc::numeric, 30)::double precision AS tamanho_mf, p.fronteira, p.regional, p.gleba_situacao, g.the_geom, g.gid AS gid_gleba, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN (p.situacao_processo = ANY (ARRAY['Requerimento Realizado'::text, 'Processo em Análise'::text])) OR p.situacao_processo IS NULL THEN count(1)
                            ELSE 0::bigint
                        END AS potencial, p.situacao_processo, g.assent_prev_nro, g.consulta_resultado
                   FROM work_rafael.vw_parcelas p
              LEFT JOIN work_rafael.dv8 d ON p.municipio_id::numeric = d.cod_mun::numeric
         LEFT JOIN fundiario.vw_glebas g ON g.gid = p.gid
        WHERE p.natureza = 'Particular'::text
        GROUP BY p.gleba, p.area_ha_utm / d.mod_fisc::numeric, p.situacao_processo, g.assent_prev_nro, g.consulta_resultado, p.id, p.fronteira, p.regional, p.gleba_situacao, g.the_geom, g.gid) t
          GROUP BY t.gleba, t.tamanho_mf, t.potencial, t.situacao_processo, t.assent_prev_nro, t.consulta_resultado, t.fronteira, t.total_parc, t.id, t.regional, t.gleba_situacao, t.the_geom, t.gid_gleba) h
  GROUP BY h.gleba, h.assent_prev_nro, h.fronteira, h.categoria, h.consulta_resultado, h.potencial, h.regional, h.gleba_situacao, h.the_geom, h.gid_gleba
```

I don´t know if I would have put it integrally, sorry if I wouldn´t. Essencially, the query joins one table and one view to provide all the infomation I want. The the_geom field came from "fundiario.vw_glebas" ("...LEFT JOIN fundiario.vw_glebas g ON ...". In FROM, we call another view, 'work_rafael.vw_parcelas', which derived from another and the another from other and so on.

I guess this is what is limiting my performance, isn´t it?

Comment: Hi Rafael, welcome to GISse!  Part of the way to improve the answer you receive is to provide as much detail as possible in your question.  I think in this case, since you are dealing with a view, which is essentially a query, including the text of the query, if you are able, would be really helpful.  627 rows doesn't seem that large, actually, and PostGIS should be able to serve it relatively quickly.  Perhaps there is something else going on.  Any detail about the query, your workspace, is Postgres installed on a server, etc, could be useful.  Thanks!

Comment: It's **not** possible to index a view, but an appropriate index on the base table(s) should suffice.  Please **edit** the question to provide more information about the tables, the view definition, the actual query, the indexes you have created, the actual query time (in seconds or milliseconds), and the query plan for the query.

Comment: Although a materialized view can be indexed, and that route might make sense if the base table cannot be modified.

Comment: A materialized view isn't really a view -- it's a table (which is why it can be indexed).

Comment: @Vince - That's the interesting thing - they're a table that functions like a view. Wikipedia considers them a view - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view

Comment: IMO, if a database object requires significant storage *and* indexing, it's a table.  The Wiki article doesn't assert "viewness" and given the detour into "snapshots", actually stresses the "tableness".  A denormalized snapshot table, joined with dynamic attributes (in a view) can sometimes give all the benefits of a materialized view, without the latency concerns.